# mongodb remote authentication failure Mongod v4

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have recently installed mongodb on one of our windows 2016 server with below configuration and running mongod as

> mongod --config C:\mongo_db\config\mongo_db_configuration.conf --auth

```
--config file
net:
    # MongoDB server listening port
    #bindIp: 0.0.0.0,192.168.43.250
    port: 27017
    bindIpAll: true
storage:
    # Data store directory
    dbPath: "C:\\mongo_db\\db"
    mmapv1:
        # Reduce data files size and journal files size
        smallFiles: true
systemLog:
    # Write logs to log file
    destination: file
    path: "C:\\mongo_db\\logs\\mongodb.log"
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

We have created a root user in admin database

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.runCommand({connectionStatus:1})
{
        "authInfo" : {
                "authenticatedUsers" : [
                        {
                                "user" : "root",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ],
                "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "root",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I am able to connect to the mongod instance locally (`mongo --port 27017 -u "root" -p "12345" --authenticationDatabase admin`) but getting error while connecting remotely.the server firewall is disabled.

```
"C:\Mongodb>mongo.exe 192.168.0.171:27017/admin -u root -p 12345
MongoDB shell version v4.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.0.171:27017/admin
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("c68e9dd5-6f7b-4356-bc3e-688a7e2b3e1d") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.4
2018-11-26T23:50:47.534+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1685:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed"
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this when I was having the same problem. I was connecting to a MongoDB server version 4.2.6 from a MongoDB shell version v3.6.9. In case anyone else finds this question like I did, here's the syntax that worked:

```
mongo --host mongodb://username:password@IP:PORT/ --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having similar issue with my virtual machines. I have 2 linux and 1 windows machine (which are remotely connected to my windows machine). Let's say Linux A has mongo with credentials. When I try to login from my windows machine, I got the same error that you mention.

However, when I connect mongo from linux B to linux A, I can successfully connect from shell using:

```
mongo --host 192.168.1.6 --port 27017 -u username -p 'pwd'
```

I use exact same command from windows as well but somehow it fails to login. Maybe this command could work on your environment but waiting for proper solution as well.